# Algorithm to match pairs from two sets

Tags: algorithm, set

I have two sets, each set is a listing of a pair of numbers

```
Set1 =[(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ..., (xN, yN)]
Set2 =[(a1, b1), (a2, b2), ..., (aN, bN)]
```

If plotted on an XY plane, Set1 and Set2 have the same basic shape, however the data points of set2 are a rotated/translated/scaled/noisy/skewed version of set1. The ordering of the pairs within each set is random. Is there an efficient way to determine which points in set1 correspond to their counterparts in set2?

Comment: The mapping needs not be unique, such as when the sets have internal symmetry.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a point in set1 "corresponds" to a point in set2?

Comment: Please explain, are you suggesting there is not a unique solution to this?

Comment: @alexraasch low euclidean distance under certain global mapping

Comment: @alexraasch, I guess it means close by some metric, e.g. euclidian.

Comment: there's no data enough to determine. or you didn't explain in a good way! and one more question, are all the pointsin set1 had the same transformation to be in the set2?

Comment: @rossb83 there needs not be a unique solution. If set1 is a square grid, then there are 8 equally good mappings

Comment: @alexraasch If for example the points in set1 formed the shape of a heart, but set2 forms an upside down heart. Which points correspond to which?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan find an affine transformation T: [x,y,z]=>[x,y,z] and mapping M: S1=>S2 such that M(s1) is near T(s1) for every s1 in S1

Comment: @mamdouh alramadan yes they are all the same transformation (save for a tiny bit of noise)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for a family of algorithms that try to minimize the difference between two point clouds.  This is a fairly hard problem to solve and there can be multiple solutions (for example, if you were given two cubes, there are many possible rotations that work).

One particularly popular approach is the [ICP (iterative closest point) algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point), which starts with a candidate guess and continuously refines it until some correctness criterion is reached or time expires.  It might be a good starting point to check out.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well these aren't randomly placed points. They form an oblong, but very well defined shape.

Comment: @rossb83- ICP is often used even if you know the two shapes are the same.  It's useful for trying to recover the way in which the points were transformed given that you know that the points define the same shape, but have no other information beyond that.

Comment: There's a significant difference between set-Shape similarity and set-Point similarity.  I'm not sure which these algorithms address?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming only Rotations, Scalings and Translations this can be done (except for the "noise" and "skew" part, that I'm not sure about).

One approach:

1. Determine the Centroid (2D mean) of each set.
2. Determine the Least-Squares (2D) slope of each set.
3. Determine the 2D Variance of each set.
4. Remap the first set, using the Centroid difference to Translate, the Slope differences to Rotate(*) and the Variance differences to Scale, so that both sets now have the same Centroid, Slope and Variance.
5. Sort both sets and then compare the points for equality/similarity. (Alternately, you can do an RSM (root-mean-square) difference between them as a measure of "noise"/difference).

(*-Note that Reflections and/or symmetries can cause problems with the Rotation part.)